# Help Desk Software with user groups and temporary ban function?

Tags: ticket-system

Does anyone know any Help Desk Software which allow you to create user groups / to mark/categorize specific users in some way / and to to ban specific users/e-mails (not user groups) for a specific period of time?

Kayako? OTRS? simpledesk?...

Kayako looks to be very functional but not sure if it has this option. zendesk is also very functional but a SaaS service not a downloadable software. Since the functions that I am saying are very common in forum software, maybe simpledesk could do it since it is based in SMF.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It is an advanced issue tracker, but can very well double up as a help desk software. Need to set the issues visibility setting to ensure that customers do not see each other's tickets.

Answer (score 0):

AJ Help Desk is the best help desk software with the robust ticket support solutions.
http://www.ajsquare.com/products/helpdesk-software/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this with Zendesk which is in my opinion the best help desk software and application, watch their videos on the most recent update to their interface. To answer your questions see these posts.

https://support.zendesk.com/forums/20004396-users-groups-and-organizations

and

https://support.zendesk.com/entries/171682-how-can-i-block-someone-from-sending-to-zendesk

Zendesk also integrated with Voip systems so you can turn phone calls into tickets as your answer them.

Answer (score -1):

IF you are look for ajax based help desk software  **[Vision Helpdesk](http://www.thevisionworld.com)**

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.